# Repeating background task Swift 3 DispatchSourceTimer

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3

I am trying to create a timer background task. I use `DispatchSourceTimer` and `DispatchQueue` with new methods Swift 3.

But it does not work...

```
var timer: DispatchSourceTimer!
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "fr.yseemonnier.app.timer", attributes: [])

timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags(rawValue: UInt(0)), queue: queue)
timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: Double(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), leeway: .seconds(1))
   timer.setEventHandler {
       DispatchQueue(label: "fr.yseemonnier.app.timer.async").async {
          print("Background task...") //refresh all 5 seconds...
       }
    }
timer.resume()
```

Thank you,

YM

Comment: "it does not work" means what? – Do you keep a reference to the timer?  Otherwise it will be deallocated. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580824/dispatchsourcetimer-and-swift-3-0 (duplicate?)

Comment: I didn't see this topic. thanks... I will close this issue.

Comment: Your time interval is approx. 158 years ;-). Use simply `.seconds(5)` and you can omit the complete `flags` parameter.

Comment: Oh. I see, thx. :S