# How to display a programatic view inside a completion handler?

Tags: swift, view, completion

I´m stuck on how to display a view from inside a completion block. If I use the same code outside the completion block the view is shown. I´m sure the block is getting executed and I also have `setNeedsDisplay` in a `didSet` for an array I use inside the block. So what am I missing?

```
private var storeViews = [UIView](){ didSet{self.view.setNeedsDisplay()}}

hrd.requestData(from: "somepage.php"){[weak self] (status:Bool,items:[[String:String]]?) in
    if status
    {
        for var i in (0..<items!.count)
        {
            if let item = items?[i]
            {
                var shape = CGRect()
                shape.size = CGSize(width: 50,height: 30)

                let xPosStr = item["xPosition"]
                let yPosStr = item["yPosition"]

                let position = CGPoint(x: (self?.stringToFloat(xPosStr!))!,y: (self?.stringToFloat(yPosStr!))!)

                shape.origin = position
                let someView = UIView()
                someView.frame = shape
                someView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                self?.view.addSubview(someView)
                self?.someViews.append(someView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear; what kind of view are you displaying?  an array would tend to indicate a tableView in which case you neet to call reloadData from the main que.  Post code.

Comment: I need the screen to have some squares so I´m using CGRect and besides of showing  them I´m storing them in an array, and the array has the didSet with the setNeedsDisplay

Comment: Can you add your code that you have so far.

Comment: How are you drawing these squares? CAShapeLayer, UIView with auto layout, UIView manual frame, UIView.drawRect()?

Comment: Hi, I just put the code (the loop doesn´t show complete because of the less than character)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `setNeedsDisplay` marks the view that it the view needs to be redrawn. This internally calls `drawRect`. You should call this only if you override `drawRect` in a `UIView` subclass with your own custom implementation. I believe you are making an asynchronous API request and you're adding the views inside the completion block. UI updates should be only done on the main thread. You need to add the subview in the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.view.addSubview(someView)
}
```

Also, since you're adding the views in a loop, you might look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744884/3066450). It has a really great explanation about the UI updates getting bottlenecked.

One more thing I noticed is,

```
for var i in (0..<items!.count)
```

If `items` is nil, your code will crash. You can do it with conditional binding to make sure it doesn't crash.

```
if let items = items{
    for item in items{
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, it solved my problem and thanks for the advice on the UI bottleneck I´m going to check it